# How to run multiple WebClients at the same time?

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

Here's my code

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < RichTextbox2.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var length = urlwebapi.Lines.Length;
        {
            WebClient f = new WebClient();
            dynamic read = f.DownloadString(urlwebapi.Lines[(i % length)] + RichTextbox2.Lines[i]);
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(read);            
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

MessageBox.Show("done");
```

*Sample urlwebapi*

```
http://example1.com/api.php?ex=
http://example2.com/api.php?ex=
http://example3.com/api.php?ex=
http://example4.com/api.php?ex=
http://example5.com/api.php?ex=
```

The code can only run one at a **urlwebapi** at the same time. How do I get when the code is executed then immediately run up to 5 **urlwebapi** (*example1.com until example5.com*) at the same time

Comment: Have a look at [DownloadStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync(v=vs.110).aspx). That should help you, process multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for how to do it:

```
public async Task<string[]> DownloadStringsAsync(string[] urls)
    {
        var tasks = new Task<string>[urls.Length];
        for(int i=0; i<tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = DownloadStringAsync(urls[i]);
        }
        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string url)
    {
        //validate!
        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            //optionally process and return
            return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

I'd prefer to use HttpClient (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) but the flow is basically the same

Comment: Or simply `return await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => DownloadStringAsync(url)));`

Answer (score -3):

I Suggest using httpClient.
That makes it a walk in the parc.. And with using you handle the dispose properly.

(pseudo-code)

```
using (var client = new httpClient)
{
  //your logic, and you can keep using client in this context.
}
```